# awk -log calculation on a column

Tags: math, awk

We would like to make -log of the 16th column.  Here is the input:

```
 95,cpd-7777777,1111,2222,IC50,,5.6,uM,3333,4444,Ki,,0.09,uM,,62.2222,2001-12-06 00:00:00,2000-02-16 00:00:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

Here the 16th column is 62.2222 so  -log(62.2222) should be "-1.79395"

However, our following effort will give a value "4.1307" instead of "-1.79395".

```
awk -F"," '{a=log($16);printf"%0.4f\n", a}'
```

It might be a silly question but stop us for almost an hour now.  May we know if there is any comment?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `log` function of `awk` calculates the natural logarithm, not the base-10 logarithm, which is the one you want. To calculate the negative base-10 log using the natural log do this:

```
awk -F"," '{a = -log($16)/log(10); printf("%0.4f\n", a)}'
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting! All the awk online tutorials which I searched yesterday didn't mention log(x) in awk is natural log.  I should have think about it yesterday lol